# Save href link in a variable and using it

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to save `<a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/b/%s">%s</a>` to a variable and use it? instead of specifying it every time as I did below, I am going to use it many times the same link with different `product`, writing a function will not help much as I will be printing the links in between some texts.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
logFormatter = logging.Formatter("[%(levelname)s]  %(message)s")
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.info('Products:')

product1="xbox"
logger.info('XBOX: (<a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/b/%s">%s</a>)<br>' %(product1,product1))
product2="surface"
logger.info('TABLET: (<a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/b/%s">%s</a>)<br>' %(product2,product2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do the string formatting in two steps. The first to fill in the template, and the second to place the generated link into the info. You'll need to use backslashes in the `link_template` in order to include the double quotes that are part of the link. Try this:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
logFormatter = logging.Formatter("[%(levelname)s]  %(message)s")
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.info('Products:')

link_template = "<a href=\"https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/b/%s\">%s</a>"

product1="xbox"
link1 = link_template % (product1, product1)
logger.info('XBOX: (%s)<br>' %(link1))

product2="surface"
link2 = link_template % (product2, product2)
logger.info('TABLET: (%s)<br>' %(link2))
```